# Display contents of pages based on the results of one div to a second div

Tags: php, html, dropdown, display

I have a question.

I have two divs next to each other. In div1 I have created a dropdown menu (10 options available) with php which allows me to open another page; based on what the user chooses.

My question is: instead of opening another page could I display the content of that page inside the second div, aka div2?

If yes, how do you do it?

More details about the issue:
practically inside the drop-down menu are 10 options available. so if you choose option 1 it opens page 1, if 2 it opens page 2 etc... so total 10 options linking to 10 different pages. My question is: instead of opening 10 pages separately how can I display the results inside a div next to the drop-down menu :-)

**something like loading content/pages dynamically (inside the div) without having to leave the page,**

I thank you in advance.

Comment: you have 10 different pages?

Comment: practically inside the drop-down menu are 10 options available. so if you choose option 1 it opens page 1, if 2 it opens page 2 etc... so total 10 options linking to 10 different pages. My question is: instead of opening 10 pages separately how can I display the results inside a div next to the drop-down menu :-) something like loading content/pages dynamically (inside the div) without having to leave the page,

Comment: You can accomplish that task using php and AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function change_page(page) 
{   
    if(page!='')
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : page,
            type : "post",
            success : function(data)
            {
                console.log(data);
                $("#div_page").html(data);
            }
        })
    }
}
</script>

<select id="sel_page" onchange="change_page(this.value)">
    <option value="">Choose page</option>
    <option value="callback.html">Page 1</option>
    <option value="page2.html">Page 2</option>
    <option value="page3.html">Page 3</option>
</select>

<div id="div_page"></div>
```

Comment: Hi paresh your code works with one exception: the sites that are loaded inside the div cannot(!) display the php contents of these sites (I have for example include footer in them)... any way around it?

Comment: if you return html from pages it will display actual output not html tags

Comment: Hi paresh I take it back... your code works perfectly... its just that the div flies out of the window when loading the content of it... I presume now its a css issue, correct? And I thank you :-)

Comment: No css also works perfectly.

Comment: no what I mean is that the div that opens extends beyond my websites width... so how can I keep it inside the boarders of the website?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe if you want to load the page inside the second div, on change of the option of first div. Second use ajax call on change of the drop down and load the content dynamically.

Comment: hi muaaz... could you provide me please with an example of let us say 2 pages (instead of 10 obviously)... and than I will adjust it for the remaining ones... I thank you in advance for that...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `<iframe>` tag. For example:

```
<?php
$newpageurl = "example.com"; //URL to be opened
$dropdowntext = <<<EOT
    <div id="div1">
        <select></select>
    </div>
    <div id="div2">
        <!--This displays the chosen URL in the <div>-->
        <iframe src="$newpageurl"></iframe>
    </div>
EOT;

print $dropdowntext;
?>
```

Adjust to your own benefit.